# How to access the properties and parts of an SSRS report at runtime

Tags: asp.net, .net, reporting-services, runtime

I'm using the ReportViewer control to display a server report in an ASP.NET page and I'm looking for a way to get the report into an object that I can then read and/or modify.

This kind of thing:

```
var rw = report.Width;
var t = ((Chart)report.Body.Item[3]).Title;
```

Is there a way, or am I stuck with parsing the XML file?

**ETA:**

I'm beginning to think I will need to access the XML file but I can't find out how to download that from the server, modify it (in memory) and then send it to the ReportViewer control.

**ETA2:**

Here's how to download the report definition (clean up left out for brevity):

```
// Download the report
var rs = new ReportingService2010();
rs.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
var reportDefinition = rs.GetItemDefinition("/DashboardReports/MyChart");

// Convert to XML
var ms = new MemoryStream(reportDefinition);
var doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
doc.Load(ms);

// To load the stream into the report viewer
stream.Position = 0; // needed because we used the stream above - doc.Load(ms)
this.ReportViewer1.ServerReport.LoadReportDefinition(stream);
```

Comment: I'm afraid you're stuck with getting, parsing, editing, and re-uploading the XML. As you're already finding out. You could probably take out a bit of your question and convert it into an answer, for future visitors.

Comment: Yeh seems that way. I'll put my answer in when it allows me...